# On an application of the chain rule.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ be continuously differentiable, then it's well know that

\begin{align*}
 f(x) & =  f(y) + \int_0^1 \frac{\partial  f (y- t(x-y))}{\partial t} \, dt \\ & =  f(y) + \int_0^1   f' (y- t(x-y)) (x-y)  \, dt 
\end{align*}

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ also be continuously differentiable. I perform the following derivation:

\begin{align*}
 g(f(x)) & =  g(f(y)) + \int_0^1 \frac{\partial g( f (y- t(x-y)))}{\partial t} \, dt \\ & =  g(f(y)) + \int_0^1 g'(f (y- t(x-y) )  f' (y- t(x-y) (x-y)  \, dt \tag{1} 
\end{align*}

I thought this derivation was correct but taking $g(f(x)) := f(x) / x^2$ and $f(x) := x^3$ I calculate $$g'(f(x)) = \frac{f'(x) x^2 - 2x f(x)} { x^4} = \frac{3x^4 - 2x^4}{x^4} =1$$
and $f'(x) = 3x^2$ and plugging this into my derivation gives

\begin{align*}
 x & =  y  + \int_0^1   (y- t(x-y))^2 (x-y)  \, dt 
\end{align*}
and this is just wrong. Where is the error in my derivation of the formula in $(1)$ and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mess about our $g$ function. I guess you want to say $ g(x)=x $, but if $ g(x)=x $, then $ g(f(x))= f(x) $ rather than $f(x)/{x^2}$. You need a clearer definition for $g$.